# Get start of day in ZonedDateTime time zone

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

Given a ZonedDateTime, how can I get a ZonedDateTime for the start of the day the time zone is in? I don't want the start of the day where it's UTC.

Example

Given
ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))

I want to return
ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))

Because June 8 1am UTC is June 7 9pm ET and I want 12am on the day that the input time is located in

Converse example

Given
ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))

I want to return
ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))

Because June 8 6am UTC is June 8 2am ET and I want 12am on the day that the input time is located in. Daylight savings is currently on for New York.

Comment: "The start of the day" is always 00:00 in every zone. Do you mean the start of the UTC day 00:00 for the zone? That would be UTC 00:00 with zone conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The `ZonedDateTime`

```
ZonedDateTime.of(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
```

represents the date time 2022-06-08T01:00:00 *in the New York timezone*, not UTC, whereas you seem to be treating this as two separate values - the date time 2022-06-08T01:00:00 in UTC, and the New York timezone. I think it would make more sense to use two separate parameters for this, for example:

```
public static ZonedDateTime startOfDayAtZone(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) {
    return instant.atZone(zone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

or

```
public static ZonedDateTime startOfDayAtZone(LocalDateTime dateTime, ZoneId zone) {
    return dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZone(zone).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

If you really want to use one `ZonedDateTime` object to represent two separate things:

```
public static ZonedDateTime startOfDayAtZone(ZonedDateTime zdt) {
    return zdt.toLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZone(zdt.getZone()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```